# Pandas: Excel subheading

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read in an excel file that has a sub-header. So far, I'm doing the following:

```
link = 'http://www.bea.gov/industry/xls/io-annual/GDPbyInd_GO_NAICS_1997-2013.xlsx'
xd = pd.read_excel(link, sheetname='07NAICS_GO_A_Gross Output', skiprows=3)
```

Unfortunately, the data has a second sub header in row 4 (0-indexed) that only gives the unit of measurement, as follows. Can I somehow cleanly ignore that row?

```
Table   IO Code Description 1997    1998    1999    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013                    
Current-dollar gross output (Millions of dollars)                                                                                               
A   1111A0  Oilseed farming 19973   17241   13259   13646   13721   14258   15672   21290   17910   18325   21425   31559   33027   34592   38524   43203   44948
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skiprows` can be a list of rows to ignore, so this does what you want:

```
xd = pd.read_excel(link, sheetname='07NAICS_GO_A_Gross Output', skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 4])
```